# Stable, open-source Servlet 3.0 container

Tags: open-source, servlets, jakarta-ee

Are there any JSR-315-capable servlet containers available besides the one in GlassFish 3? Neither Tomcat nor Jetty have stable versions that support the Servlet 3.0 API.

Comment: You're excluding the JBoss 6 pre-release milestone builds too?

Comment: I find it very disappointing to see that Tomcat has no plans to support the Java EE 6 web profile (the Tomcat guys said that there was no demand for this but I believe that SpringSource actually pushed in this direction). And my prediction is that Java EE 6 web profile implementations will get traction (and "pure" Servlet/JSP will loose traction) and that not much innovation will happen with Tomcat (Sun/Oracle was a *major* contributor but this is the past, they are now focusing on GlassFish).

Answer (score 0):

[Resin](http://www.caucho.com/) [4.0.1](http://www.caucho.com/resin-4.0/changes/resin-4.0.1.xtp#Servlet%203.0%20Early%20Access) and newer supports Servlet 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

[JBoss Web](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb) passes the Serlvet 3.0 TCK since [version 3.0.0 Beta 1](http://remm.blogspot.com/2010/01/jboss-web-passes-standalone-servlet-30.html). It didn't reach GA though.

Answer (score 0):

[Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html) supports Servlet 3.0

Answer (score 0):

[jetty 8](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Jetty_Version_Comparison_Table) and newer supports Servlet 3.0.